# Asking road related questions

Tags: discussion

I just noticed on a [question migrated to aviation.se](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/why-does-schiphol-airport-have-such-a-long-taxi/), that travel.se is described as "site for road warriors and seasoned travelers.". I have never noticed the road warriors part before. Does this mean that questions on roads in general are on topic on travel.se? To me that actually makes sense. People driving are actually traveling.

It also suddenly makes sense to me why expats should have separate site (Contrary to the consensus I have always considered expat question to be on topic here). Expats aren't " seasoned travelers".

I had a proposal running on area 51, called [on the road](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61056/on-the-road/), which I am considering to reopen, but reading the "road warriors" part in the description the questions I had in mind for "on the road", might as well be asked here.

Personally, I would consider that a welcome addition to all those visa questions.

Answer (score 4):

In computing, a road warrior is [a mobile worker who is constantly on the road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_warrior_%28computing%29).

That'll be, I suspect, what the original person meant when they named it.

In case you're wondering, the 'slogan' comes from the [original proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel), where Slavo specified the description as such.

Comment: So no Road questions :(
But then expat questions (being road warriors) are on topic ;)

Comment: Did you read the link? An expat is not a road warrior :)

Comment: @MarkMayo http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/6591/revisions Credit should go to Robert

Comment: Minor quibble— *[road warrior](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/road%20warrior)* as a term for someone constantly on (long-distance) travel for business predates mobile computing (and in most industries, even personal computing). The archetypical road warrior is the salesman, joined by the regional manager, the retail buyer, the field engineer, and the employment recruiter.

Comment: @Bernhard huh, had never noticed that, well spotted. Also interesting that it used to mention Chris Guillebeau in the name - I saw him at WDS in Portland in July.